# How to get details of metadata objects in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a list of metadata  objects from my repository. I've fetched all SASLibrary, PhysicalTable, Jobs objects. Now I need to fetch all their details. Can someone please suggest how can I do that? I am new to SAS DI and need to fetch the details using SAS code.
Thanks

Comment: provide more information

Answer (score 2):

ok, assuming you have a dataset (`have`) which contains those objects, and that the uri is stored in a variable called `uri` then the following should suffice:

```
data associations;
  keep assoc assocuri name;
  length assoc assocuri name $256;
  set have;
  rc1=1;n1=1;
  do while(rc1>0);
    /* Walk through all possible associations of this object. */
    rc1=metadata_getnasl(uri,n1,assoc);
    rc2=1;n2=1;
    do while(rc2>0);
      /* Walk through all the associations on this machine object. */
      rc2=metadata_getnasn(uri,trim(assoc),n2,assocuri);
      if (rc2>0) then do;
        rc3=metadata_getattr(assocuri,"Name",name);
        output;
      end;
      call missing(name,assocuri);
      put arc= rc2=;
      n2+1;
    end;
    n1+1;
  end;
run;
proc sort data=associations;
  by assoc name;
run;

proc sql;
create table groupassoc as
  select assoc, count(*) as cnt
  from associations
  group by 1;

data attrprop;
  keep type name value;
  length type $4 name $256 value $32767;
  set have;
  rc1=1;n1=1;type='Prop';
  do while(rc1>0);
    rc1=metadata_getnprp(uri,n1,name,value);
    if rc1>0 then output;
    n1+1;
  end;
  rc1=1;n1=1;type='Attr';
  do while(rc1>0);
    rc1=metadata_getnatr(uri,n1,name,value);
    if rc1>0 then output;
    n1+1;
  end;
run;
proc sort data=attrprop;
  by type name;
run;
```

This information can also be obtained using `metabrowse` in Base SAS.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I'm not very familiar with metadata identifiers, but I reckon Metadata Id for every object is to be used as the URI. As you had suggested I used this code to get the metadata objects github.com/Boemska/macrocore/blob/master/meta/mm_getobjects.sas and renamed Id to URI. I used it to get obejcts for Physical tables, Sas Libraries and Jobs. Will the code help me get all the details like path for jobs/libraries/tables, and other attributes for all these types of objects?

Comment: ^^ that's another question :-)

Comment: I tried the code but I did not get much details on the attribs, like the physical path, schema names,etc. I've posted a more explicit question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095004/sas-metadata-objects-details-saslibraries-physicaltables-jobs

Answer (score 0):

for example call this macro for metaobjects intereseting to you. The fullList table  will contains all your interesting objects with metaId and object type:

```
    options Metaport=portnumber;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    options MetaUser="userid";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    options Metapass="password";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    options MetaServer="serverName"; 
    options metaprotocol=bridge;

    data fullList;
    length objName $60 objId $17 objType $50;;
    delete;
    run;

    %macro getMeta(objType);
            data temp(keep=objType objName objId);
                length uri $256 objName $60 objId $17 objType $50;
                uri="";n=1;TableName="";
                objType="&objType";
                    do while(metadata_getnobj("omsobj:&objType?@Id ? '.'",n,uri) >= 0);
                            rc=metadata_getattr(uri,"Name",objName);
                            rc=metadata_getattr(uri,"Id",objId);
                            n=n+1; 
                            output;
                    end;
            run;
            proc append base=fullList data=temp;
            run;
    %mend;
    %getMeta(Person);
    %getMeta(PhysicalTable);
    %getMeta(Job);
    %getMeta(JFob);
    .
    .
    . if you want .....
```